# Как при помощи pymorphy3 перевести в родительный падеж всё предложение целиком?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymorphy2

Могли бы вы помочь с модулем pymorphy3? Хочу перевести в родительный падеж фразу целиком и получить "первого числа месяца", но это не работает с фразой:

```
spasibo = ("первое число месяца")
morph = pymorphy3.MorphAnalyzer()
one = morph.parse(spasibo)[0]
spasibo = (one.inflect({'gent'}).word)
```

только с отдельными словами, а как склонять предложения целиком?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае можете просто разбить предложение на отдельные слова и просклонять их по отдельности, а потом обратно собрать предложение:

```py
import pymorphy3

phrase = "первое число месяца"
morph = pymorphy3.MorphAnalyzer()
result = ' '.join(morph.parse(word)[0].inflect({'gent'}).word for word in phrase.split())
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
первого числа месяца
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! На будущее я также хочу убрать все лишние символы (знаки препинания) из фразы, если они туда случайно попадут. Каким образом мне это сделать?

Comment: если в фразе присутствуют союзы (и, в, о, с и т.д.) эта конструкция перестаёт работать. Как прописать такие исключения?

Comment: Про пунктуацию легко гуглится, это стандартный процесс. Исключаете из фразы всё, что есть в `string.punktuation`. А насчёт союзов - добавьте примеры в ваш вопрос, что получается сейчас и что бы вы хотели. Хотя скорее всего это уже совсем не простой случай.

Comment: пунктуация удаляется добавлением к фразе следующего фрагмента: .translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))

Comment: с союзами так и не разобрался, есть вариант исключать по совпадению

Comment: Союзы обычно короткие, можно не преобразовывать строки короче трех или четырёх символов, ну как вариант. Ну или исключения сделать, да

Comment: представил решение ниже

Answer (score 0):

вот способ как исключать из морфологического анализа знаки препинания и союзы:

```
import pymorphy3
import string

text = "первое число месяца, дня и года".translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))

morph = pymorphy3.MorphAnalyzer()
words = text.split()
conjunctions = [word for word in words if morph.parse(word)[0].tag.POS == 'CONJ']
sentence = [word for word in words if word not in conjunctions]
st = (' '.join(sentence))
status = ' '.join(morph.parse(word)[0].inflect({'gent'}).word for word in st.split())

print(status)
```

вывод

```
первого числа месяца дня года
```

Comment: Разве это ответ на ваш вопрос - про склонение предложения? Где тут склонение собственно? Вопрос был совсем о другом. Нужно привести вопрос и ответ в соответствие. Либо дополните вопрос, так, чтобы этот ответ на него отвечал. Либо переделайте ответ так, чтобы он отвечал на вопрос. Либо переделайте и то и другое.

Comment: извиняюсь, поправил))